# how to loop through urls in a firebase firestore set function?

Tags: javascript, firebase

The code below is looped for let's say, 7 times. I am using firebase setting documents btw. If I want a document that recieves multiple fields, so like url1, url2 => url7, how can I do this? I've tried url[i], url{i} where i is the index being looped.

```
db.doc().set({
   url: downloadURL
}){ merge: true });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer. goodtalk.

```
db.doc('someDocument').set({
    ['url' + index]: downloadURL
}),{ merge: true };
```